How to Call addLiquidityETH in uniswap v2 router from solidity smart contract?
I'm trying to call addLiquidityETH function in uniswap V2 Router, but the transaction keeps failing.
This is the code i used to call addLiquidityETH function.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "./IUniswapV2Router01.sol";

contract TestUniswapLiquidity {
  address private constant ROUTER = ROUTER_ADDRESS;

  event Log(string message, uint val);

  function addLiquidityETH(
    address _token,
    uint _amountTokenDesired
  ) external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "ETH must be provided");
    require(_token != address(0), "Invalid token address");

    // Transfer tokens from sender to this contract
    IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountTokenDesired);
    
    // Approve the router to spend tokens
    IERC20(_token).approve(ROUTER, _amountTokenDesired);

    // Add liquidity using ETH and tokens
    (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) =
      IUniswapV2Router01(ROUTER).addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(
        _token,
        _amountTokenDesired,
        0,
        0,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
      );

    emit Log("amountToken", amountToken);
    emit Log("amountETH", amountETH);
    emit Log("liquidity", liquidity);
  }
}

Not sure what's the mistake, need help to add liquidity from smart contract.

probably need to call approve before calling your contract.
